# Improve the link text of the magic link [help/on-topic]

Tags: feature-request, magic-links

The link text of some magic links is a precise phrase,
for example `[ask]`, linking to `/help/how-to-ask`, will have the link text "How to Ask".

But `[help/on-topic]`, linking to `/help/on-topic`, will have the link text "help center", which is overly generic.
You have to hover over the link to know the page it's pointing to.
It would be better if that was obvious from a more precise link text itself.

Can you please change the link text of `[help/on-topic]` to "Help Center > Asking", or similar?

Answer (score 9):

I just found your question while searching ahead of asking the same thing.

I fully agree.  It's so helpful to have

- `[ask]` expand to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- **Nice**
- `[mcve]` expand to [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  -- **Nice**.

Yet

- `[help/on-topic]` expands to [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). -- **Yuck.**

It instead should be:

- `[help/on-topic]` expands to [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). -- **Nice.**

or something else that's better than just *help center*.

Comment: I'd like to see the same for `[help/dont-ask]`.

Answer (score 2):

Nice. I've tried using custom link titles in my comments instead of the magic links just for this reason. The default "help center" isn't specific enough.